# Opening web page within existing web page

Tags: c#, .net, webbrowser-control

I need to be able to load web pages from different sites within a page on my site. I am using C# .NET and master pages. Within the content page, I want to be able to load an arbitrary page and display it without any of the browser controls appearing - just the page content.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you not just use a boring old `iframe`?

```
<iframe src="http://stackoverflow.com" width="900" height="500"></iframe>
```

Comment: Updated with example. And yes, please accept some answers on your previous questions. You have lots of accurate answers to choose from.